# how to get cell cellphone signal from far away

Tags: cellphone

I am starting a ranch and would like fast internet.
The ranch is 50km away. What equipment do I need to catch the cell signal from the city? What I need is internet that I try to get by  cell phone.

Comment: Cellphone networks do nothing for you if you only can listen the signal. You must be able to send as well. Making yourself audible at 50 km away will not become simple. Your antenna must be lifted to about 40 meters above the ground to cross the horizon assuming the other end does the same and you must generate (with power and antenna directivity) much more higher radiation intensity than what is allowed for cellphones. 50km is also a substantial signal delay when compared to the ordinary. Unfortunately I do not know enough to tell does it cause signalling time out.

Comment: you could try for this ... https://www.starlink.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your best option might be a line-of-sight link, depending on the local geography.  You would need a dish antenna at either end and some medium-power transceivers, I’d guess about 20 to 50W for that range.  I know of an experimental setup that was built several years ago where they managed to get a wifi signal over about 10km just using special home-made antennas, so 50km doesn’t seem unachievable with a reasonable amount of power.  I suppose you would need a cell modem in the city on a tall building or tower, linked to a line-of-sight transceiver.  It’s a bit of a project though, probably not something to undertake if you haven’t done anything similar before.  You might be better off waiting a few months for Starlink to come online.

Comment: so it would be like point to point connection?

Comment: Yes exactly, with a cell modem at one end and your ranch network at the other.

Comment: there is no other option that point to point?

Comment: There are a few but that’s the most practical one.  If you’re not bothered about getting a cell signal to the nearest city then you might consider Inmarsat.  If you have unlimited resources you could run a fibre, but if you want a radio-based solution then point-to-point is what you need (what would be the purpose of any other topology?).

Comment: I will not be able to get point-to-point,I can not get access to any tower or high point in the city,I have not any property there